# How to formulate a linear programming model where the rates of production must be calculated?

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming, constraint-programming

A friend of mine is working on this problem for a course. I will post the problem in full and tell you what my/our thoughts are on it.

[image: problem]

The problem then asks for a model that can be used to develop a daily production schedule for each plant as well as the optimal solution.

Here is the rest of the problem in the book. I hope it's legible.

[image: rest of problem]

I am familiar with problems in which there are two variables which I can then graph and produce a feasibility region. I can then test the vertices of the region against the optimization equation.

$C_1$: the total produced of Component 1.
$C_2$: the total produced of Component 2.

$$C_1 = C_2$$

$B_1$: the total of Component 1 produced in Buffalo.
$B_2$: the total of Component 2 produced in Buffalo.
$D_1$: the total of Component 1 produced in Dayton. 
$D_2$: the total of Component 2 produced in Dayton.

$$C_1=B_1+D_1=B_2+D_2=C_2$$

$$B_1\le 2,000$$
$$B_2\le 1,000$$
$$D_1\le 600$$
$$D_2\le 1,400$$
$$C_1\le 2,600$$
$$C_2\le 2,400$$

In the example given, $60\%$ of Buffalo's production time is used on component one. I could express this as $R_{B1} = 0.60$, signifying the amount of resources Buffalo puts into Component 1. Then:

$$R_{B1}+R_{B2}=R_{D1}+{R_D2}=1$$

Furthermore:

$$2,000R_{B1}+1,000R_{B2}=B_1+B_2\le 3,000$$
$$600R_{D1}+1,400R_{D2}=D_1+D_2\le 2,000$$

And

$$2,000R_{B1}+600R_{D1}=1,000R_{B2}+1,400R_{D2}$$
$$2,000R_{B1}+600R_{D1}=1,000(1-R_{B1})+1,400(1-R_{D1})$$

It's also noted that we only need to maximize one plant.

> EDIT: I *said* that, but it wasn't a part of the problem. I'm doubting now that it's so.

If this is the optimization equation...

$$C_1=2,000R_{B1}+600R_{D1}=C_2=1,000R_{B2}+1,400R_{D2}$$

... *can I rewrite everything in terms of $R_{B1}$ and $R_{D1}$, and graph those as variables? How can I go about this?*

EDIT:

Another way of looking at it is this. Any thoughts?

[image: constraint diagram]

I'm thinking that the factories won't operate at 100% efficiency. If they did, then $C_1$ would not equal $C_2$ and *that* would be inefficient. (I'm reminded of [*The Goal* by Elyahu Goldratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_constraints).)

So, do we need to test the vertices of that small triangle? How?

EDIT (again): I'm inclined to think that we find $C_1$ and $C_2$ by taking the intersection between the $C_1 = C_2$ line and the *Dayton* line. Then we could feed that results back in to the equations

$$C_1=2,000R_{B1}+600R_{D1}=C_2=1,000R_{B2}+1,400R_{D2}$$

to solve for $R_{B1}$ and its kin. Am I on the right track?

Comment: "It's also noted that we only need to maximize one plant." It is necessary to post the question word by word to avoid misunderstanding. What are the questions ?

Comment: @calculus That quote was an idea my colleague had. I'm beginning to doubt it. At any rate, I've added the rest of the problem from the text, so there is no doubt about what's being asked.